# How we include a joomla module in a component view in joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I am working in a Joomla site I want to include a module inside a component view anybody help me. I am using this code it display unauthorized access message.

```
    <div class="used_image">
<?php
    include($mosConfig_absolute_path."/modules/mod_MODULENAME/mod_MODULENAME.php");
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Here is some more options about load module to [custom position](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/5056/how-to-display-module-in-component-area)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this

```
  jimport('joomla.application.module.helper');
    // this is where you want to load your module position
    $modules = JModuleHelper::getModules('header'); 
    foreach($modules as $module)
    {
    echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($module);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks this is working fine for me in 2.5. Is there a way to ensure in the same time modules loaded this way are not displayed in other part of the page at the same time?

Comment: By using renderModule the module is rendered inside the component body (in main <div> tag). Is there any way to load the module into any other position inside custom component view files ?

Comment: Does anybody know how to declare these position for the backend selection?